# Compiling XZ Utils for Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries, lzma, xz

I am trying to compile the XZ-utils code for use in the Android NDK. I follow the same procedure that I used to correctly compile the libogg and libtheora libraries. However, it does not work to create the liblzma library of XZ-Utils. This is the procedure I use:

1) Go to the folder containing the library source.

```
cd ~/Drivers/xz-5.0.5
```

2) Configure the Autotool makefile with

```
./configure --prefix=/home/rb/Drivers/xz --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-debug
```

3) Make the library and specify the toolchain to be used for compiling (which is located in /opt/ndk/):

```
make CC=/opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CXX=/opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ LD=/opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
```

When running the 3rd command, I get the following errors:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src'
Making all in liblzma
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma'
Making all in api
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma/api'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma/api'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma'
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I../../src/liblzma/api -I../../src/liblzma/common -I../../src/liblzma/check -I../../src/liblzma/lz -I../../src/liblzma/rangecoder -I../../src/liblzma/lzma -I../../src/liblzma/delta -I../../src/liblzma/simple -I../../src/common -DTUKLIB_SYMBOL_PREFIX=lzma_  -pthread -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wredundant-decls -g -O2 -MT liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.Tpo -c -o liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.lo `test -f '../../src/common/tuklib_physmem.c' || echo './'`../../src/common/tuklib_physmem.c
libtool: compile:  /opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/liblzma/api -I../../src/liblzma/common -I../../src/liblzma/check -I../../src/liblzma/lz -I../../src/liblzma/rangecoder -I../../src/liblzma/lzma -I../../src/liblzma/delta -I../../src/liblzma/simple -I../../src/common -DTUKLIB_SYMBOL_PREFIX=lzma_ -pthread -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wredundant-decls -g -O2 -MT liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.Tpo -c ../../src/common/tuklib_physmem.c -o liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.o
mv -f .deps/liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.Tpo .deps/liblzma_la-tuklib_physmem.Plo
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I../../src/liblzma/api -I../../src/liblzma/common -I../../src/liblzma/check -I../../src/liblzma/lz -I../../src/liblzma/rangecoder -I../../src/liblzma/lzma -I../../src/liblzma/delta -I../../src/liblzma/simple -I../../src/common -DTUKLIB_SYMBOL_PREFIX=lzma_  -pthread -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wredundant-decls -g -O2 -MT liblzma_la-common.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblzma_la-common.Tpo -c -o liblzma_la-common.lo `test -f 'common/common.c' || echo './'`common/common.c
libtool: compile:  /opt/ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/liblzma/api -I../../src/liblzma/common -I../../src/liblzma/check -I../../src/liblzma/lz -I../../src/liblzma/rangecoder -I../../src/liblzma/lzma -I../../src/liblzma/delta -I../../src/liblzma/simple -I../../src/common -DTUKLIB_SYMBOL_PREFIX=lzma_ -pthread -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wredundant-decls -g -O2 -MT liblzma_la-common.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblzma_la-common.Tpo -c common/common.c -o liblzma_la-common.o
In file included from common/common.c:13:
common/common.h:92: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'
common/common.h:135: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'lzma_code_function'
common/common.h:238: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'
common/common.c:73: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'in'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_next_filter_update':
common/common.c:114: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'update'
common/common.c:115: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'update'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_next_end':
common/common.c:126: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'end'
common/common.c:127: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'end'
common/common.c:133: error: unknown field 'code' specified in initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
common/common.c:133: warning: initialized field overwritten
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous).init')
common/common.c:133: warning: initialized field overwritten
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous).init')
common/common.c:133: error: unknown field 'end' specified in initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:133: error: unknown field 'get_check' specified in initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:133: error: unknown field 'memconfig' specified in initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:133: error: unknown field 'update' specified in initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:133: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_strm_init':
common/common.c:156: error: unknown field 'code' specified in initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
common/common.c:156: warning: initialized field overwritten
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous).init')
common/common.c:156: warning: initialized field overwritten
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous).init')
common/common.c:156: error: unknown field 'end' specified in initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:156: error: unknown field 'get_check' specified in initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:156: error: unknown field 'memconfig' specified in initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c:156: error: unknown field 'update' specified in initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
common/common.c:156: warning: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_code':
common/common.c:180: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'code'
common/common.c:253: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'code'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_get_check':
common/common.c:331: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'get_check'
common/common.c:334: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'get_check'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_memusage':
common/common.c:345: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
common/common.c:346: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_memlimit_get':
common/common.c:362: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
common/common.c:363: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
common/common.c: In function 'lzma_memlimit_set':
common/common.c:380: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
common/common.c:386: error: 'lzma_next_coder' has no member named 'memconfig'
make[4]: *** [liblzma_la-common.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src/liblzma'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rb/Drivers/xz-5.0.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea what causes this error, or more importantly, how it can be solved. I searched for these errors, but could not find a solution. For me it seems like a mistake in the common/common.c file of the source code, but I consider this very unlikely as somebody else would surely have found it earlier. Does anybody know how to correctly compile the XZ Utils for the Android NDK?

**UPDATE**
I got the library to compile, although I still have no clue what is wrong with the above procedure. Compiling worked by configuring the makefile with

```
./configure --prefix=/home/rb/Drivers/xz --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --enable-static --with-pic --disable-xz --disable-xzdec --disable-lzmainfo --disable-scripts --disable-lzmadec --disable-shared
```

and instead of the `make` command I directly used the `make install` command (with the same compiler paths).

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? XZ for Java is quite slow, so I will have to make a JNI wrapper for the native version, so if you have a working solution ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Steps for building XZ

You can download XZ from its git repo by running this:

```
git clone https://git.tukaani.org/xz.git
```

The former is useful when building for various architectures; thus you can run (within source root directory):

```
git clean -dfx
./autogen.sh
```

I have my NDK in */home/osboxes/dev/android-ndk-r16b*, thus I separated it into 3 architectures, by running the following:

```
cd /home/osboxes/dev
~/dev/android-ndk-r16b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --use-llvm --arch=arm --install-dir=android-ndk-arm --force
~/dev/android-ndk-r16b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --use-llvm --arch=x86 --install-dir=android-ndk-x86 --force
~/dev/android-ndk-r16b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --use-llvm --arch=arm64 --install-dir=android-ndk-arm64 --force
```

## For ARM

```
CC=~/dev/android-ndk-arm/bin/clang CFLAGS="-fPIE" LDFLAGS="-pie" ./configure --prefix=/home/osboxes/dev/libs/arm --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --enable-static --disable-xz --disable-xzdec --disable-lzmainfo --disable-scripts --disable-lzmadec --disable-shared
```

## For ARM64

```
CC=~/dev/android-ndk-arm64/bin/clang CFLAGS="-fPIE" LDFLAGS="-pie" ./configure --prefix=/home/osboxes/dev/libs/arm64 --host=aarch64-linux-android --target=aarch64-linux-android --enable-static --with-pic --disable-xz --disable-xzdec --disable-lzmainfo --disable-scripts --disable-lzmadec --disable-shared
```

## For x86

```
CC=~/dev/android-ndk-x86/bin/clang CFLAGS="-fPIE" LDFLAGS="-pie" ./configure --prefix=/home/osboxes/dev/libs/x86 --host=i686-linux-android --target=i686-linux-android --enable-static --disable-xz --disable-xzdec --disable-lzmainfo --disable-scripts --disable-lzmadec --disable-shared
```

After each configuration you must run:

```
make -j2
```

Options "*-j2*" uses 2 CPU for building process. You can change the number of CPUs you want to use, or even remove this option. To install compiled sources then run:

```
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

just point configure's CC to your cross compiler and compile it as static . do not use any other flags